# Can't create build definition from VS2008 connected to TFS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build

We are working with  VS2008 connected to TFS2012. We have a requirement that if anyone do checkIn changes,then latest version files must be copied to a central folder that is not mapped with TFS. I had done some searching and then i found that if we can do this with build events and all i have to do is create new build definition with triggering at checkin. I have created build definition but while giving ok this error occured.

[image: build error]

How to create build definition?Or is there any other way to  copy latest version files on CheckIn event?

Thank you

Comment: Gee, my guess from reading that message is that you need VS2010 to be able to use that functionality.

Comment: I thought so,but we needed to create build definition in VS2008 only.Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the VS2008 Compatibility GDR for TFS 2012? You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29983).

Comment: I dont think we can connect to TFS2012 using VS2008 without installing VS2008 Compatibility GDR and yes i have installed that. And still i am not able to create build definition.